# Where can I find a Client for the Google Docs Data API for Android?

Tags: android, google-docs-api, google-api-java-client, google-docs

I have downloaded `google-api-java-client` libraries from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) .

I also have downloaded `picasa-android-sample`.

There is an Object called `PicasaClient` in `picasa-android-sample`which is used to login and access data.

I have found a `DocsClient` from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-gdocs-api/).
But it doesn't look like an Object I can use like `PicasaClient`.

Could you please tell me where I can find something like `DocsClient` which works like `PicasaClient`.

Even better if someone can kindly tell me where I can find a sample code for using `Google Docs` on Android.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've got the DocsClient object from shared-sample-docs-v3-1.1.0.jar.  
 I am trying to use executeGetDocumentListFeed method of DocsClient.  
 But executeGetDocumentListFeed seems to be the ONLY ONE method of DocsClient.  
 What should I do if I want to upload/download documents?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [My Tracks](http://mytracks.appspot.com/) app source. It has both document and spreadsheet row manipulation example. Source code isn't particularly elegant and reusable per se, but contains some useful hints for communicating with GDocs.